# How to use enterprise library in aspnet5 rc1 / mvc6

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core, enterprise-library, asp.net-core-mvc

1. How to use Enterprise Library in Aspnet5 web application project? which nuget package should be used?
2. In earlier asp.net website, web.config was used to specify configSections, dataConfiguration, defaultDatabase, cachingConfiguration. How / where to specify these values in Aspnet5

Comment: I am afraid to tell you that we (who have invested a lot in Unity), will have to give up soon and move to another solution. Please refer to this link
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/ Although I have seen some few implementations to use unity with MVC6, yet I recommend to look around and extend out minds for better solution. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext/

Answer (score 0):

As to the configurations..Asp.NET5/MVC6 has another way of doing the configurations, it can read configurations at any format and most known are json, ini and Xml.

If you have your configurations in web.config, you still can read them and go through them one by one.

```
    <configuration>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="Trace">
    <listeners>
      <add name="General Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" fileName="General.log" formatter="One Liner Formatter" header="" rollInterval="Day" traceOutputOptions="Callstack" asynchronous="false" asynchronousBufferSize="3000" />
      <add name="Exception Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" fileName="Exceptions.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollInterval="Hour" rollSizeKB="100" traceOutputOptions="Callstack" filter="Error" asynchronous="false" asynchronousBufferSize="3000" />
      <add name="Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" fileName="Trace.log" footer="" formatter="One Liner Formatter" header="" rollInterval="Day" traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId" asynchronousBufferSize="3000" />
      <add name="SecurityAudit Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" fileName="SecurityAudit.log" footer="" formatter="One Liner Formatter" header="" rollInterval="Day" traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId" asynchronousBufferSize="3000" />
      <add name="Unprocessed Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" fileName="Unprocessed.log" footer="" formatter="One Liner Formatter" header="" rollInterval="Day" rollSizeKB="0" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack" asynchronous="false" asynchronousBufferSize="3000" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}" name="Text Formatter" />
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Timestamp: {timestamp(local)} Message: {message} Category: {category}  Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId} Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}|)}" name="One Liner Formatter" />
    </formatters>
```

You can read it like

```
            var config = new Configuration()
                   .AddXmlFile(@"conf.xml");
 var formatterName = config["loggingConfiguration::listeners:add:General Trace Listener:formatter"];
            var logFileName = config["loggingConfiguration::listeners:add:General Trace Listener:fileName"];
            var rollInterval = config["loggingConfiguration::listeners:add:General Trace Listener:rollInterval"];
```

then you can use these variables to build LoggingConfiguration object and pass it to the logger..

like

```
using (LogWriter defaultWriter = new LogWriter(config))
                {
                    var log = new LogEntry { Message = message };
                    defaultWriter.Write(log);
                }
```

This seem to be cumbersome effort, if you prefer to use Xml parser, then go ahead but the best way is to look for the parser in EL since it is open source and it is reading the configuration the same way you to.